# How to eliminate an unused cached css file?

Tags: css, wordpress, caching, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I am using Google PageSpeed Insights to evaluate my site, at https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=en&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.datanumen.com%2F

There is one opportunity "Reduce unused CSS" and under this category, there is one CSS file:

https://www.datanumen.com/wp-content/cache/min/1/wp-content/themes/datanumen/style.css?ver=1625535579

This file seems to be a cached version of style.css. How to implement this opportunity?

Currently I am using WP Rocket as the Cache Plugin.

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/53-clear-wp-rocket-cache#clear-cache-for-post may help.

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet is NOT unused, its only that some of the rules in that sheet is not being used for styling that page hence the issue. WP-Rocket combine all the stylesheet into one big file hence many of the style rules go unused.

Only if you are willing to create stylesheet for each individual page only then such issues can be resolved.